# How to return an error if a field is null else return all rows during JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, isnull

I have the following tables

```
TableA(Field1,Field2)
TableB(Field3,Field4)
```

Now I am selecting values in these tables and returning. However, if the field 3 in `TableB` is `null`, return an error.

My procedure for this is as follows

```
create proc name
@Field1 varchar,
@Field2 varchar,
@Field3 varchar out,
@Field4 varchar out,
@Error  varchar out
AS
BEGIN

SELECT @Field2  = tA.Field2, 
@Field3 =   tA.Field3,
FROM tA C INNER JOIN TableB tB ON
tA.Field1 = tB.Field1                   
WHERE tA.Field4 = @Field4
```

I do not know how to return error if Field 3 is null

I am thinking to write another query for checking is null for this table

Comment: Sound like you need do validations in your db, like use insert triggers or `not null` property. But return error because result have a null value is bad practice.

Comment: If you need text error use `SELECT @Field3 = ISNULL(tA.Field3, 'Error')...` or `SELECT @Field3 = COALESCE(tA.Field3, 'Error')...` or `SELECT @Field3 = CASE WHEN tA.Field3 IS NULL THEN 'Error' ELSE tA.Field3 END...`

Comment: @lad2025: Thank you, it is resolved through some IF ELSE. (Easy way for me :) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use RAISEERROR for use defined error
[More on RAISEERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

```
create proc name
@Field1 varchar,
@Field2 varchar,
@Field3 varchar out,
@Field4 varchar out,
@Error  varchar out
AS
BEGIN

SELECT @Field2  = tA.Field2, 
@Field3 =   tA.Field3,
FROM tA C INNER JOIN TableB tB ON
tA.Field1 = tB.Field1                   
WHERE tA.Field4 = @Field4


if @field is null
begin

    RAISERROR ('Fields 3 cannot be null .', -- Message text.
               16, -- Severity.
               1 -- State.
               );
end
else 
    select @Field2 as Field2, @Field3 as  Field3
```

Comment: No man, this is not optimized way. I am looking for something else

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for raising error message:

```
   BEGIN TRY
         IF @Field3 IS NULL
            RAISERROR ('Fields 3 cannot be null .', 16,1);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       SET @Error = ERROR_MESSAGE()

    END CATCH
```